# Como fazer os elementos de uma tupla serem os argumentos de uma função em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tupla

Primeiro resumirei o problema para depois explicar o que eu estou tentando fazer. Se souber responder o problema resumido, nem precisa ver o resto. Existe uma maneira de passar os elementos de uma tupla como argumentos de uma função? Por exemplo:

```
tupla=(arg1,arg2,arg3)

def f(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)

f(tupla)
```

Nesse script, args é uma tupla que tem um elemento  que é uma tupla. Porém, o que eu quero é que args seja uma tupla com os 3 elementos. Ou seja, isso printará:

```
(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

Porém eu quero que printe:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

Agora direi o que eu quero fazer. Trabalhando com tkinter, pensei em criar uma função única para alterar janelas. Inicialmente fiz isso:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master=master

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 1').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela2')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',self.janela2)
        self.button.pack()

    def janela2(self,event):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 2').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela3')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',self.janela3)
        self.button.pack()

    def janela3(self,event):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 3').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela4')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event,arg1='Argumento1',arg2='Argumento2':self.janela4(event,arg1,arg2))
        self.button.pack()

    def janela4(self,event,arg1,arg2):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 4').pack()
        self.label2=Label(self.master,text=arg1).pack()
        self.label3=Label(self.master,text=arg2).pack()

    def destroy_all_widgets(self,frame):
        for i in frame.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()

root=Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Porém gostaria de fazer algo do tipo:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master=master

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 1').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela2')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event,function=self.janela2:self.go_to_window(event,function))
        self.button.pack()

    def janela2(self,event):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 2').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela3')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event,function=self.janela3:self.go_to_window(event,function))
        self.button.pack()

    def janela3(self,event):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 3').pack()
        self.button=Button(self.master,text='Janela4')
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event,function=self.janela4,args=('Argumento1','Argumento2'):self.go_to_window(event,function,args))
        self.button.pack()

    def janela4(self,event,arg1,arg2):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Aqui é a Janela 4').pack()
        self.label2=Label(self.master,text=arg1).pack()
        self.label3=Label(self.master,text=arg2).pack()

    def destroy_all_widgets(self,frame):
        for i in frame.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()

    def go_to_window(self,event,function,*args):
        self.destroy_all_widgets(self.master)

        if len(args)==0:
            function(None)
        else:
            function(None,args)

root=Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Basta chamar a função como `f(*tupla)`. O `*` converte a tupla para os parâmetros da função.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pegando seu primeiro exemplo, basta fazer:

```
tupla=(arg1,arg2,arg3)

def f(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)

f(*tupla)
```

O operador `*` como prefixo de um parâmetro, ou elemento de uma sequência ou iterador, "desdobra" o conteúdo daqueles argumentos naquele ponto.
(E o operador `**` faz  a mesma coisa para dicionários e argumentos com nome)